# Wordpress on Google App Engine with own server

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want run Wordpress on GAE using my own MySql server. I have install Wordpress using tutorial http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ and edit wp-config.php to don't use Cloud SQL:

```
define('DB_HOST', '**mysql server ip**');
define('DB_USER', '**wordpress user**');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '**user password**');
```

It works properly at localhost, but when I load any page of project at appspot it returns 500 Server error. And I see this warning message at development console log:

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110
> Safari/537.36 CoolNovo/2.0.9.20" "wp-blog.gentle-ally-698.appspot.com"
> ms=401 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 exit_code=204
> instance=00c61b117cd4ccc78b6c87c3678ee520deb2d8ab
> app_engine_release=1.9.10
>
> W 19:45:20.193 A problem was encountered
> with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This
> is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to
> your application. (Error code 204)

Is it because I use own MySQL server instead of Cloud SQL? In this case, is there any ways to run Wordpress on free account? Otherwise, what can be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to external MySQL servers, you'll need to enable sockets, which requires a billing account: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/